# Linq query help c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to write a linq query.

I need my query to take a 2 dimensional array (d). It needs to check for each array within d if the first and last elements are not empty but any element within is empty, it will remove the empty element.

Example

```
{{test,"",test}, {test, test, test,"",test}} = {{test,test}, {test, test, test,test}}
```

But I need to be able to keep empty strings so cannot just search for them and remove them.

I hope I have explained that well enough.

Comment: I can check the first and last element very simply in linq so have done I am struggling with how to check the middle elements and get the result over each array.... not sure where to start with that....

Comment: @user101010101 "but I need to be able to keep empty strings so cannot just search for them and remove them." .. how are u planning to keep them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
var out = input.Select(x =>
       ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FirstOrDefault()))
        && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LastOrDefault())))
           ? x.Where(y => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(y)).ToArray()
           : x).ToArray();
```

If you only need IEnumerables you can probably remove the ToArrays.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
string test = "test";
var array = {{test,"",test}, {test, test, test,"",test}};

string[] TransformRow(string[] inputRow)
{
  return intputRow.Where(cell => cell != string.Empty).ToArray();
}

var validArray = array.Select(row => TransformRow(row));
```